Can't query record from ServiceResourceSkill object
I need to query record from object ServiceResourceSkill in apex class but system return no record event thought there're still records inside it. Here some informations:

I ran this apex class by a user with Salesforce license, but not System Administrator profile

This profile is also granted permission to ServiceResource object. I couldn't find ServiceResourceSkill in the list standard object to  grant permission to it.

Even when I tried to query ServiceResource records, system returns no value as well

The Apex Class is 'with sharing' class

The query like this, where agentId is the id of current log in user:


SELECT EffectiveStartDate, EffectiveEndDate, SkillId, SkillLevel, ServiceResource.RelatedRecordId FROM ServiceResourceSkill WHERE ServiceResource.RelatedRecordId = :agentId


When I tried the query above in Query editor, system still return a list of 5 records.

Please help to explain why this issue is happen, and how to solve it. Thank you!

What is the api version of apex class which is used?

The 'with sharing' keyword enforces the sharing rules of the current user. If the user running the class does not have permission to see those records, the query will return no records.
